# #Aframe Can i get the position of the laser point instead of the object's position?

Tags: aframe

I need to show the distance of two points(not two objects) by using controller-cursor-component, but I only find the way to show the distance between the intersecting object and camera.

Is there any good way to solve it?
Sorry, I'm a newbie of Aframe, any advice will be appreciated!

```
<html>

<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hello, WebVR</title>

<script src="test/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>   
<script src="lib/aframe/aframe-controller-cursor-component.js"></script>

<script AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
  init: function () {

  this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.detail.intersection.distance);

    });
  }
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a-scene id="scene"  stats>

<a-entity id="cameraRig"  position="0 28 6">
  <a-entity id="head" camera  look-controls orbit-controls  wasd-controls></a-entity>
 <a-entity id="righthand" vive-controls="hand: right" controller-cursor ></a-entity>
 </a-entity>

<a-entity cursor-listener id="Element_1090" class="FireOne1" gltf-model="url(model1205/1-Fire_one/Element_1090.glb)"
  gps-place="lon:121.434540342353; lat:25.2012249857784; height:33.133450"></a-entity>

  </a-scene>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It needs more context and code to reproduce. The more info the easier for people to help you

Comment: https://github.com/bryik/aframe-controller-cursor-component    i use this component, and i want to get the laser point's position in aframe world

Comment: Provide a complete runnable with the whole context, to see what you've tried and how you are using that component. https://glitch.com/ is a good option

Comment: @DiegoMarcos here's my code, i got the distance between object and camera, but i want the position of laser point or the disdance between two laser points(not two objects), do you have any good advice? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you mean by laser point, but I will assume its the right hand entity.
But essentially to calculate the distance between two objects you can use the Vector3 .distanceTo function.
See the docs here for the function: [Vector3.distanceTo](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.distanceTo)

Basically, I would do something like this: (i haven't tested the code, its just to show you the direction)

```
let rh = document.querySelector('#righthand');
this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  let distance = evt.currentTarget.object3D.position.distanceTo(rh.object3D.position);
});
```